# uploading sessions with php not outputing

Tags: php

I want to view data stored in an uploading session but all I get is 'Null', am I going about this the wrong way?

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $target = "test/";
     $target = $target . basename('test') ;
     $file = ($_FILES["uploaded"]["name"]);
     $key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . $_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")];

    var_dump($_SESSION[$key]);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)){echo "done";}else echo "error";
}
```

and the html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="test" />
   <input type="file" name="uploaded" />
   <input type="submit" name='submit' />
</form>
```

Comment: what you're getting on `ini_get('session.upload_progress.enabled')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get upload progress status when upload is already done.

If you want to make it working, then  you can for example send your form to iframe and during the upload ask server, using ajax, what is the status.

I would suggest to use it rather as a fallback for older browsers cause currently browsers are supporting ajax upload and you can display upload progress without making additional requests to server and creating some strange hidden iframes ;)